# I can't see what went wrong with this WinJS.xhr call

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I'm using `WinJS.xhr` to call a ReST service... when I call the url on the browser I can see the complete returned xml. So I want to parse that xml to show some of the data.

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://myserver/myservice" }).
    then(processPosts, downloadError);
```

The problem is my `downloadError` function does not have parameters so I have no idea what went wrong.

What am I missing?

The [help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx) is not very helpful :(

**Edit:** I used to [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to see what's on the wire and I don't see the request. The server I'm targeting is my own LAN, I also tried with its IP Address with same results (none)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is an error the callback function will take one parameter. The downloadError will need to take in one parameter. If you define downloadError as follows you should get more details. The result type should be XMLHttpRequest and using that you can see the status of the request and why it failed.

```
function downloadError(result){
//check the result param.
}
```

**EDIT:**

Check the app capabilities in your application.AppManifest file. The capabilities section is where you define what capabilities are required by your app for example connect to the internet, use the webcam.

Comment: I have the result but it is empty (?), I inspect it and there's nothing there that will show me a message or something... I have no clue what's going on

Comment: yes I have... I don't even see the request... maybe I should add that to the question

Comment: If you are not seeing the request 1. Are you trying to make connection localhost? 2. In your app manifest have you selected the option to connect to internet/intranet?

Comment: YES, that's what it was! I had no idea about the `App Capabilities`... please add that to your answer so I'll set it as correct! thanks!